# How do i get touch event on WebView

Tags: iphone

Hope you all are fine and also in one of your best moods!!

I have one problem in Map based application. kindly go through it and post your suggestion.

Thing at Glance:

I need to integrate map in my application.
application shows map based on passing parameter as state and city.

i am using yahoo map image for that.

i.e.

pass parameter as following:

state : CA
city : Loss Angelous.

it shows image of map perfectly that i load on webview.

now issue is here:

i need to put button at selected city.. i don't know how do i put.

because on clicking button i need to load another view that contains Details of that city.

I don't know how do i do this.

Kindly give your suggestion.

Thank you.

Arun Thakkar.

Answer (score 0):

Using the iPhone SDK 3.0 you can use the MKMapKit framework to embed a map in your application, and you can add custom annotations. Here's the [MKMapView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html).